# Handlebars two or more if condition in comparsion

Tags: if-statement, handlebars.js, logical-operators, handlebarshelper

I want to check two more condition in IF Helper in Handlebars.

Can some one help me with it.

i want something like the below one :

```
 status = "success";
 {{ifCond status '==' 'success' && status '==' 'pass'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my mind you have a problem because status can't be at the same time pass and success...

Use 2 variable instead status and check for example :

```
{ "status" : "success" , "check" : "pass" }
```

You can have more than just one parameter in a helper :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function( cond1, cond2) {
   if (cond1 == 'success' && cond2 == 'pass') {
      return "OK";
   } else {
      return "KO";
   }
});
```

the code in your template will look like that :

```
{{ifCond status check}}
```